# Putting JSON into array and into UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios4, sdk

Say I have some JSON data:

```
[{"id":"1","case_name":"NZXT Phantom 
410","case_description":"","case_type":"ATX","case_color":"White","case_price":"99.99","case_i
mage":""},{"id":"2","case_name":"Thermaltake 
MK+","case_description":"","case_type":"ATX","case_color":"Black","case_price":"84.99","case_i
mage":""}]
```

I've already fetched it into an NSString but I can't seem to figure out how I can put it in a NSArray like:

```
 parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            [[part alloc] initWithpartName:@"Penguin" imageName:@"penguin.jpg"],
            [[part alloc] initWithpartName:@"Crow" imageName:@"crow.jpg"],
```

Also I use this code to return the cell:

```
part *part = [parts objectAtIndex:(indexPath.indexPath.row)];
cell.label.text = part.partName;
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:part.imageName];
```

the Part class looks like:

```
@interface part : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * imageName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * partName;

- (id) initWithpartName:(NSString*)part imageName:(NSString*)image;
```

How could I use SBJSON parser to convert this json code into an nsarray: `parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:`

Comment: Have you read the documentation of SBJSON?

Comment: I was looking at several tutorials but Ill take a look.

Comment: good, if it doesn't work even after, I'll try to come up with a solution.

Comment: I think I still need help. I'm not understanding the difference between array and dictionary

Comment: an array is an ordered list of elements - in an array containing n elements, there's an element corresponding to an integer from 0 to (n - 1), such as "1. cat, 2. dog, 3. bird". A dictionary is essentially a key-value storage - while the order of its elements is unspecified, a unique key correponds to each object, similar to an address book: "name" = "Jon Skeet", "Reputation" = "470000";

Comment: ok so mine would be a dictionary within an array. What would I need it to be in to put it in a tableview?

Comment: exactly, a doctionary in the array! Now think about it a bit! Obtain the array - it will contain exactly one element, the dictionary. Get the dictionary using `[theArray objectAtIndex:0]`, then you can use the elements of the dictionary to provide data to the table view.

Comment: Ok I think I get it. One last thing: The "theArray" would be whatSBJSON gets or would it just be the json string?

Comment: NSDictionary dict = [jsonarray objectAtIndex:0]; right?

Comment: right. And of course it's the array, not the string. You have to parse the JSON beforehands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
- (NSArray *)partsFromJSONString:(NSString *)JSONString
{
    NSData *JSONData = [JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *JSONArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData
                                                         options:0 error:NULL];
    NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *object in JSONArray) {
        Part *part = [[Part alloc] initWithPartName:object[@"case_name"]
                                          imageName:object[@"case_image"]];
        [returnArray addObject:part];
    }
    return returnArray.copy;
}
```